# .NET Core API sending broadcasts to connected apps?

Tags: android, api, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm looking into options for sending location data between an Android app and a .NET Core Web API at a predefined rate (say, every 10 minutes).

At the moment it's working via Android Foreground Services by sending the location to a API endpoint - but that all changes in Android 8.0 and becomes unreliable.

I'm wondering if a better way to do this would be to get the API to broadcast a ping to every mobile device that is currently tracking, and ask for a location report. If they do not receive a location back within a specific timeframe, then the tracking session could be considered terminated.

Has anyone done something similar? I'm currently looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 2.1 is currently in [preview](https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup), but includes support for [SignalR](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) which would allow you to ping all connected devices like you are describing.

Here are some [samples](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples). I recommend reading [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-getting-started-with-signalr/).

An [unofficial SignalR client for Android](https://github.com/Gurgen/SignalR-.net-core-android-client) is also available (I haven't tested it yet). Official SignalR clients are [here](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/tree/dev/clients) (I've used the TypeScript client in Angular with .Net Core 2.1 Preview 2 successfully).

So this may not meet your immediate needs, because it's in preview release right now, but once 2.1 is finally released, it will be a great option for this use case.